# Simpler than YAML, better than CSV

Tags: xml, json, csv, yaml

I need a very simple input language for my customers' needs. Among those I know (`XML`, `JSON`, `YAML`, `CSV`), `XML` and `JSON` can't be used ("not damn human-readable").

`CSV` is too simple for my tasks (there are some hierarchies, and some attributes maybe attached to "items")
and `YAML` is too complicated. ("documentation? *TL;DR*")

Is there some well known standard that can fill the gap between `YAML` and `CSV`? Or I'll need do it by myself?

The question arose because I have no time to reinvent the wheels.

**UPD**:   (after some discussion)

My "language" should be similar to CSV, but not so simple.
There is a definition (schema, template, pattern) of the tree structure  (somwhere, it's not my deal).
I have to define the human-readable language for it's data storage.

Informal examples of various "patterns":

```
Class -> kind -> species  
Menu -> submenu -> sub-submenu
Panel -> subpanel -> control
```

Examples of corresponding content

```
animals [cat, dog, elephant {big, gray}],
plants [deciduous [oak, maple, baobab],
      other [fir, cactus]
]

File [New, Open, Save, Remove {disabled}],
View [Text [ANSI {default}, UTF-8],
     Binary, HTML],
Help [On-line, Forum, About]

Header {height:10} [Welcome, Controls [Help Button, Search Pane]],
Main [Teaser, News, Articles [1, 2, ..., N]],
Footer [Status Bar [?, ?], Powered By, Copyright notice {color: gold}]
```

So my preliminary definition of the required language is:

```
Nodes are delimited by ',' (comma) or \n (line feed)
Node may have optional set of attributes (in curly brackets)
Node may have optional set (array) of subnodes (in square brackets)
```

If there is something similar in the world in use then I should see it to avoid pitfalls.
Otherwise I should patent my new ingenious language))

Comment: silly question: why would you want to reivent the wheel and not use something already widely used? People that will have to deal with your custom "simpler-than-yaml-better-than-csv" thing (maintainers) will hate you for putting them to having to learn Yet Anoter Markup Language (no pun intended.).

Comment: Very good question) I just did not want to invent anything. I offered them to use XML.  
The problem arose when it was discovered that all tags have turned to === `<node>`.  
They hate the unnecessary angle brackets ... So I need "like XML" but without tags (?).

Answer (score 1):

There is an [RFC published](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.html) for configuration files.

The format looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
skip-external-locking
old_passwords = 1
skip-bdb
skip-innodb
```

It works like this:

```
[section_name]
my_variable = my_value
```

You can have multiple sections, and each of them can have as many variables as you want. It's not as powerful as `JSON` or `XML` since you can have more than 1 nested elements, but you could work it around like this:

```
[section1]
my_var = 2

[section2]
parent_section = section1
my_other_var = 3
```

Of course, you would have to write some code to deal with this use case, but it keeps the syntax pretty clear, and depending on your needs this format might be enough.

I don't know what language you're going to use, but there is an [implementation in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) (and probably in most languages)

It gives something that is human readable, easy to parse, and pretty powerful.

Edit: The example is coming from the Python documentation (see link above).

Comment: Confusing complicated) they need something with a half-page description ...   
I suddenly thought the XML would probably OK, but "without these horrible angle brackets". May be using tabs to do nested level of? Do you know such one language?

Comment: I'll clarify my answer

Comment: OK, it may be a way out. I have to think. Thanks for impetus)

Comment: what language are you using? You could give it a try, and see if it suits your requirements.

Comment: The programming language does not matter now. We are still at the prototype stage. (BTW: I found my very old `C` code where I parse 'windows.ini'))  
The formal specification of the input language is much more important, because it will be very difficult to correct later.  
If I find a suitable formalism, then we can discuss the parsing details. I prefer `javascript`, but any server-side language is also fine.
I talked with customers and I will clarify my question ASAP

Comment: Not a 100% sure, but I think `.ini` is more for windows. I think they're different. The wikipedia page doesn't mention the RFC anywhere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: The linked RFC (RFC 822), has *absolutely* nothing to do with configuration files, or the common (but non-standard) "INI" format described in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'm answering in favor of future Googlers.

You could use s-expressions like in scheme/lisp, which is fairly simple for humans to read/write if well idented and it should be easy to find a free parser for any language.

Python tuples are very similar to scheme/lisp, with the downside of being more quoted-verbose and needing coma for separation instead of whitespace, but with the upside of being immediately parseable in python.

You could ident it like this:

```
(
    animals
    (
        cat
        dog
        (
            elephant
            (
                big
                gray
            )
        )
    )
)
```

or like this:

```
(animals
    (cat
    dog
    (elephant
        (big
        gray))))
```

I didn't think of this myself, but instead got the idea from here:
http://jsdelfino.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/simpler-than-json.html